# Average of values in Excel from different cells excluding zero

Tags: excel

I have a set of values that I want to find the average for.  The values are in different cells, not near each other. The value of zero should not be considered.

- E.g.1 in cell `A1` I have 5, in cell `C4` I have 7, in cell `Z2` I have 0.
- E.g.2 in cell `A1` I have 5, in cell `C4` I have 7, in cell `Z2` I have 8.

---

- In E.g. 1 the average should be (5+7)/2
- In E.g. 2 the average should be (5+7+8)/3

I would like to achieve this using Excel functions with no hard coding of any values.  I am aware that if the values were next to each-other, e.g. in cells `A1,A2,A3` I would do `=AVERAGEIF(A1:A3,">0")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume that the condition 'not zero' can be hardcoded.  Also that the cell locations can be, since they're disjoint.

You can implement your own:

```
=SUM(A1, C4, Z2)/SUM(A1>0, C4>0, Z2>0)
```

It's a little cumbersome, but Excel doesn't appear to let you use the `*IF` functions on disjoint ranges.  You could always use a hidden cell range, but it sounds like you don't want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Overkill for 3 cells but this approach can be extended to use discontinuous ranges, if required, rather than individual cells

`=SUM(E1,C4,Z2)/INDEX(FREQUENCY((E1,C4,Z2),0),2)`

Answer (score 0):

This works for your example:

```
=AVERAGEIF(INDIRECT({"A1","C4","Z2"}),">0")
```

Comment: While this works, it's dangerous on two fronts. Firstly, it hardcodes cell references, meaning if you add or remove rows/columns within the used range, it will then point at the wrong numbers. Secondly, INDIRECT is volatile, meaning any cells downstream in the calculation chain will be recalculated any time you perform any action. (See my post https://chandoo.org/wp/2014/03/03/handle-volatile-functions-like-they-are-dynamite/ for more on this)

Comment: Agreed on both points, and INDIRECT isn't always appropriate. (I love it in so many ways though).

Answer (score 0):

An undocumented feature is that you can join disjoint ranges with a colon.

AVERAGEIF(A1:A1:A5:A5:A7:A7, ">0")

In other words, you can string together ranges of the form start:end:start2:end2, by using colons.  If using single cells, you have to use that cell as both start and end, as shown